# How to create live images Content Block in marketing cloud using Content Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I want to create a Live content block in the Content builder. but I can't find any specific option for creating the live content block. 
lets say I want to display today's date or Weather in my block. so how can I get that option for creating the live content? 
According to the Marketing Cloud docs, we will get the Live Image block in Advance Content section. 
or do I need to raise any ticket for that.

Answer (score 3):

Normally it would be enabled through a SFMC Support Case, but right now it's available only on those SFMC instances where it was already requested. They are not provisioning it for new instances at the moment.

[**Live Images**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_live_image.htm&type=5):

> We are temporarily suspending Live Image provisioning, but we are supporting accounts that are already provisioned.

For the [**Live Weather**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_live_weather_block.htm&type=5) Block you will need to contact your AE for the pricing.

Comment: Ok got it. So right now I can't open a case with SFMC. they are enabling it in the first quarter of 2020. Thanks, Rain.